# Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW()

Tags: php

Im starting to develop a count viewers online system and Im having a issue.
I usually use time(NOW()) to get time but now its giving me this error:

*Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW()*

Do you have any ideia why this is happening?

```
$id_session= $_SESSION['startView']['session'];
if($_SESSION['startView']['time_end'] <= time())
        {
            $delete = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM viewers_online WHERE session=? OR time_end <= ? ");
            $delete->bindValue(1,$id_session);  
            $delete->bindValue(2,time(NOW()));
            unset($_SESSION['startView']);  
        }
```

Comment: `NOW()` is a MySQL function which you cannot call in `bindValue()`.

Comment: thanks for your info! Im new at PDO and so I´m still with old habit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$delete = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM viewers_online WHERE session=? OR time_end <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())");
$delete->bindValue(1,$id_session);  
unset($_SESSION['startView']);
```

Comment: Thank you, but my delete its not also working with that method! :S

Comment: did you do this at the end :   $delete->execute(); ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `NOW()`, use `new DateTime()` which is a proper php function. `NOW()` is a mysql function. Creating a new DateTime() is the equivalent of NOW().

Comment: This isn't always the case. It depends on the format of the date field. Using NOW() always fits all date fields in MySQL as opposed to using PHP datetime which is in a certain format.

Comment: Yes, I was saying now what Aziz said because Im comparing to a time like: "1393361554"